# Android Socket Read Problems

Tags: java, android, sockets

I have created a socket that connects to a Raspberry pi hot spot. I am able to successfully connect to it and send a string to the pi. However, since I have tried to implement read functionality to get data from the pi, I have had some issues.

Every time I run the while loop or just have a "response = myBufRead.readLine()", the program stalls.

```
private class StatusCheck extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {


    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        //debug vibrations and text
        if(vibrate) {
            Vibrator vib = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
            vib.vibrate(100);
        }
        try {
            InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);
            Log.d(debugStr, "In initial connect");
            mySocket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);

        } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (mySocket == null) {
                str1 = "Socket became null";
                return null;
            }
            str1 = "Connected";
            try {
                PrintWriter myPrintWriter = new PrintWriter(mySocket.getOutputStream(), true);
                InputStreamReader myInputStreamRead = new InputStreamReader(mySocket.getInputStream());
                BufferedReader myBufRead = new BufferedReader(myInputStreamRead);
                Log.d(debugStr, "In out created");

                myPrintWriter.write(recordName);

                Log.d(debugStr, String.valueOf(myBufRead.ready()));
                Log.d(debugStr, "About to enter while loop");
                while((response = myBufRead.readLine()) != null) {
                    Log.d(debugStr, "in while loop");
                    response = myBufRead.readLine();
                    Log.d(debugStr, String.valueOf(myBufRead.ready()));
                    Log.d(debugStr, myBufRead.readLine());
                    Log.d(debugStr, String.valueOf(myBufRead.ready()));
                }
                Log.d(debugStr, "out of while loop");
                myPrintWriter.close();
                myInputStreamRead.close();
                myBufRead.close();


            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                mySocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

    }


}
```

Anyone know why this is happening? Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BuffereadReader.readLine()` is a blocking method, so it will wait and, as you say, "stall" its thread until it has something to read. Are you calling `flush()` after you write to the stream from your pi?

Another issue might be that `readLine()` will wait for a complete line, i.e. it will wait until it reads a line separator character. Are you sending a line separator character from your pi? See [Socket Multithreading - Reading input stream pauses thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30004153/socket-multithreading-reading-input-stream-pauses-thread)

You can do (from the pi end, assuming you're using a [`BufferedWriter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#write-int-)):

```
bufferedWriter.write(text);
bufferedWriter.newLine();
bufferedWriter.flush();
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! That clears things up a bit. I will test it and see what happens.

Comment: Ok it turns out the pi code was not properly flushing and readLine did not know when to stop, like you said. Thank you so much!

Comment: `readLine()` reconginzes all three possible line terminators. Your final paragraph is therefore not correct.